# Script to automate recovery of MySQL password

Tags: shell

I have a LAMP server running on OpenSUSE 12.3. Sometimes I need to recover my MySQL password and I do these steps every time:

1. Stop mysql (`service mysql stop`)
2. Edit /etc/my.cnf ( `vi /etc/my.cnf` )
3. In the server section add `skip-grant-tables`
4. Start Mysql (`service mysql start`)

At this stage you will be able to login to mysql just fine (no passwords will be prompted)

Now in console:

1. `mysql`
2. `use mysql;`
3. `insert into user (Host, User, Password) values ('localhost','root','');`
4. `update user set Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',Crea Event_priv='Y', Trigger_priv='Y', Create_tablespace_priv='Y' where user='root'; quit;`

(All these commands are run in mysql console or via phpmyadmin)

Now the above commands tell mysql to create root user (as it does not exists in the distribution)

And we are all set, now revert back

1. Edit my.cnf (`vi /etc/my.cnf`)
2. remove: `skip-grant-tables`
3. `mysqladmin shutdown`
4. `service mysql start`
5. `mysqladmin -u root password XXXXXXXXXX`

I want to automate this process when I have to recover my MySQL password.

Comment: -1: i think you could ask some freelancers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
service mysql stop
vi /etc/my.cnf
# In the server section add skip-grant-tables
service mysql start

mysql
use mysql;
insert into user (Host, User, Password) values ('localhost','root','');
update user set Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',Create_Event_priv='Y', Trigger_priv='Y', Create_tablespace_priv='Y' where user='root';
quit;

vi /etc/my.cnf
# remove skip-grant-tables
mysqladmin shutdown
service mysql start
mysqladmin -u root password XXXXXXXXXX
```

You should recognise the code, it's pretty much what you asked. The missing bits are for you to separate the MySQL commands from the shell commands, or to wrap them as an invocation of mysql:

```
mysql -D mysql ...
```

Also, consider placing the password in a suitably protected file or passing it as an argument to your script.